# prove that $P(n,m)\le\frac{n}{m}$ where $P(n,m)$ is number of ways we can factor $n$ to multiple of numbers not less than $m$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, induction

Suppose $P(n,m)$ is number of ways we can factor $n$ to multiple of numbers greater than $m$,

e.g $P(36,2)=5$ $(36 = 6\times 6 = 4\times 9 = 3\times 12 = 3\times 4\times 3)$

prove that $P(n,m)<\frac{n}{m}$

I guess I should use induction on n to prove it but I don't know where to start.

Comment: What is the bound on $P(n, 1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim:**$\;$For all positive integers $n,m$ we have $P(n,m) < {\large{\frac{n}{m}}}$.

**Proof:**

It's immediate that $P(n,m)=0$ if $m\ge n$.

Proceeding by strong induction on $n-m$, let $d$ be the least value of $n-m$ for which the truth of the claim has not yet been established.

Necessarily $d > 0$.

Let $n,m$ be positive integers with $n-m=d$.

Let $k$ be the largest nonnegative integer such that $(m+1)^k{\,\mid\,}n$.

For each integer $j$ with $0\le j\le k$, the number of factorizations of $n$ with all factors greater than $m$ and exactly $j$ factors equal to $m+1$ is equal to
$$
P\left(\frac{n}{(m+1)^j},m+1\right)
$$
which, by the inductive hypothesis, is less than
$$
\frac{n}{(m+1)^{j+1}}
$$ 
hence we have
\begin{align*}
P(n,m)
&=
\sum_{j=0}^k P\left(\frac{n}{(m+1)^j},m+1\right)
\\[4pt]
& <
\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{n}{(m+1)^{j+1}}
\\[4pt]
&=
\frac{n}{m}\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{m+1}\right)^{k+1}\right)
\\[4pt]
& <
\frac{n}{m}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which completes the induction.